# Two columns of line numbers in VSCode. Is this a bug?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Was switching around editors quickly in VSCode when suddenly I got two columns of line numbers on one of my files. Is this a feature or a bug?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the double column of numbers when you are looking at the Source control view of a file with changes, where you have narrowed the window so much that it decides to show a single panel, not two side-by-side files each in their own panel.

For example, if I widen my window, I get this display:
[image]

But if I narrow it, I get this:
[image]

So it's a space-saving feature, not a bug. 8-)